# How can I get apt autoremove to clean up after a failure?

Tags: apt

While trying to set up a cron job to autoremove packages I ran into an issue with the `apt autoremove -y` command where it failed and now I cannot see how to rerun the operation. Here's what I tried:

1. In a shell, I ran `sudo apt autoremove` which presented me with a list of "linux-aws-headers" type packages to remove.

   ```
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree
   Reading state information... Done
   The following packages will be REMOVED:
     linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1090 linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1092 linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1094 linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1095 linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1096 linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1098 linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1099 linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1100 linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1101 linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1102 linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1104 linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1105 linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1106 linux-headers-4.4.0-1090-aws linux-headers-4.4.0-1092-aws linux-headers-4.4.0-1094-aws linux-headers-4.4.0-1095-aws linux-headers-4.4.0-1096-aws
     linux-headers-4.4.0-1098-aws linux-headers-4.4.0-1099-aws linux-headers-4.4.0-1100-aws linux-headers-4.4.0-1101-aws linux-headers-4.4.0-1102-aws linux-headers-4.4.0-1104-aws linux-headers-4.4.0-1105-aws linux-headers-4.4.0-1106-aws linux-image-4.4.0-1090-aws linux-image-4.4.0-1092-aws linux-image-4.4.0-1094-aws linux-image-4.4.0-1095-aws linux-image-4.4.0-1096-aws linux-image-4.4.0-1098-aws linux-image-4.4.0-1099-aws linux-image-4.4.0-1100-aws linux-image-4.4.0-1101-aws linux-image-4.4.0-1102-aws linux-image-4.4.0-1104-aws
     linux-image-4.4.0-1105-aws linux-image-4.4.0-1106-aws linux-modules-4.4.0-1090-aws linux-modules-4.4.0-1092-aws linux-modules-4.4.0-1094-aws linux-modules-4.4.0-1095-aws linux-modules-4.4.0-1096-aws linux-modules-4.4.0-1098-aws linux-modules-4.4.0-1099-aws linux-modules-4.4.0-1100-aws linux-modules-4.4.0-1101-aws linux-modules-4.4.0-1102-aws linux-modules-4.4.0-1104-aws linux-modules-4.4.0-1105-aws linux-modules-4.4.0-1106-aws
   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 52 to remove and 54 not upgraded.
   After this operation, 1,746 MB disk space will be freed.
   Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
   ```
2. I created a cron with `apt autoremove -y` to do this instead
3. The cron job ran, but did not clean up the space as I expected. I checked /usr/src/ and all of the linux-aws-headers contents are still present, but a subsequent run of `sudo apt autoremove` shows me no packages to remove

   ```
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree
   Reading state information... Done
   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 54 not upgraded.
   ```
4. On another machine I ran the cron with `apt autoremove -y > somefile` to inspect the output, which said:

   ```
   Reading package lists...
   Building dependency tree...
   Reading state information...
   The following packages will be REMOVED:
     linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1090 linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1092
     linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1094 linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1095
     linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1096 linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1098
     linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1099 linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1100
     linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1101 linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1102
     linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1104 linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1105
     linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1106 linux-headers-4.4.0-1090-aws
     linux-headers-4.4.0-1092-aws linux-headers-4.4.0-1094-aws
     linux-headers-4.4.0-1095-aws linux-headers-4.4.0-1096-aws
     linux-headers-4.4.0-1098-aws linux-headers-4.4.0-1099-aws
     linux-headers-4.4.0-1100-aws linux-headers-4.4.0-1101-aws
     linux-headers-4.4.0-1102-aws linux-headers-4.4.0-1104-aws
     linux-headers-4.4.0-1105-aws linux-headers-4.4.0-1106-aws
     linux-image-4.4.0-1090-aws linux-image-4.4.0-1092-aws
     linux-image-4.4.0-1094-aws linux-image-4.4.0-1095-aws
     linux-image-4.4.0-1096-aws linux-image-4.4.0-1098-aws
     linux-image-4.4.0-1099-aws linux-image-4.4.0-1100-aws
     linux-image-4.4.0-1101-aws linux-image-4.4.0-1102-aws
     linux-image-4.4.0-1104-aws linux-image-4.4.0-1105-aws
     linux-image-4.4.0-1106-aws linux-modules-4.4.0-1090-aws
     linux-modules-4.4.0-1092-aws linux-modules-4.4.0-1094-aws
     linux-modules-4.4.0-1095-aws linux-modules-4.4.0-1096-aws
     linux-modules-4.4.0-1098-aws linux-modules-4.4.0-1099-aws
     linux-modules-4.4.0-1100-aws linux-modules-4.4.0-1101-aws
     linux-modules-4.4.0-1102-aws linux-modules-4.4.0-1104-aws
     linux-modules-4.4.0-1105-aws linux-modules-4.4.0-1106-aws
   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 52 to remove and 54 not upgraded.
   After this operation, 1,746 MB disk space will be freed.
   dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
   dpkg: warning: 'start-stop-daemon' not found in PATH or not executable
   dpkg: error: 2 expected programs not found in PATH or not executable
   Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
   ```

Clearly `PATH` was problematic as can be seen in the output. I set PATH in the cron job, but a manual run of `sudo apt autoremove` still shows `0 to remove` despite the disk space still being used. Is my apt all messed up now such that I need to manually rm from /usr/src?

Comment: you may be looking for `apt clean;apt autoclean` that removes *.deb files from /var/cache/apt !
also think of a script that contains correct path set and apt commands , with right permissions, in the right /place/ and use it from cron.

`apt install -f` will attempt to fix any issue